# PyCharm doesn't resolve Django apps but the project works

Tags: django, pycharm

This is the project structure generated from having run `django-admin startproject school` and `python manage.py startapp quiz`:

[image]

In `INSTALLED_APPS` I've added:

```
"quiz.apps.QuizConfig",
```

In order for this project to execute correctly, in `school/quiz/views.py` I have to import e.g. models from `quiz.models` instead of the commonly seen `school.quiz.models`. Otherwise the project fails to run:

[image]

As you can see above, PyCharm doesn't recognize `quiz`. It wants me to use `school.quiz` instead, but when I do that the project doesn't run:

```
  File "/.../Code/breather/school/school/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from quiz.views import QuestionView
  File "/.../Code/breather/school/quiz/views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from school.quiz.models import Question
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'school.quiz'
```

I'd really prefer to use `school.quiz`, but I can live with using `quiz` if needed. I just want PyCharm and `runserver` to reconcile on one way so that I can get on with my project.

These are my Django settings in PyCharm:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use "from .models import Question"

Comment: Fair enough, that works, in the example I gave, but then `from ..quiz.views import QuestionView` doesn't work in school/school/urls.py: `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: I guess that'd be "from quiz.views import Question View"

Comment: Thanks, but that also generates the red squigglies in PyCharm. :/

Comment: You're welcome. You can just ignore the red stuff, I don't really know why PyCharm's like that. You'll get to see quite a number of such :) I also get irritated but I've gotten used to it.